# How can I make Google Hangouts open in a new tab?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, google-plus

Whenever I join a new Hangout it pops up a new window. But not even a real window, it's a useless modal thing that I can't even open new tabs in.

What I normally do is copy the link from the modal window, close it, and open a new tab with that link. But that means people see me pop in and out and get confused.

Is there a way to open Hangouts in new tabs by default? I can't find a Chrome extension to do this for normal Hangouts, and not Hangouts On Air.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IF you hold down the CTRL key while clicking, the hangout should open in a new tab.

There is a list of keyboard shortcuts supported by Chrome here:

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/157179?hl=en

Comment: Command on Mac OS. Works for me!

Answer (score 1):

Also for macOS users I've found that when Google Chrome or Safari is in Full Screen mode video call will be created in the new tab instead of new window. So, you can go to fullscreen before calling.

This method also works when you going to make new call pushing big round button on the front Hangouts page.

I can't say about another operating systems except macOS, would be great if someone says in comments about Windows and Linux.